# Mostrar datos en GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Estoy intentado hacer una aplicación sencilla donde se muestra un *GridView*, pero la aplicación, no muestra el *GridView*. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
public class AdapterCategory extends BaseAdapter{

    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<Categoriaç> item;

    public AdapterCategory(Activity activity, ArrayList<Categoriaç> item){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.item=item;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return item.size();
    }
    public void clear(){
        item.clear();
    }
    public void addAdll(ArrayList<Categoriaç>item){
        for(int i=0; i < item.size(); i++){
            item.add(item.get(i));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0){
        return item.get(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.objeto, null);
        }
        Categoriaç dir = item.get(position);

        TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        description.setText(dir.getTexto());

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivCalendar);
        imagen.setImageDrawable(dir.getImagen());

        return v;
    }
}
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<Categoriaç> Categoria = new ArrayList<Categoriaç>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        AdapterCategory adapter = new AdapterCategory(this, Categoria);

        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}   
public class Categoriaç {

    private String texto;
    private Drawable imagen;

    public Categoriaç(){
        super();
    }   
    public Categoriaç(String texto, Drawable imagen){
        super();
        this.texto=texto;
        this.imagen=imagen;
    }   
    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }   
    public void setImagen(Drawable imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }   
    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }   
    public Drawable getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }
}
```

El layout *activity_main*:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</GridView>
```

Y el layout *objeto*:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivCalendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Imagen"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivCalendar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivCalendar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivCalendar" />
```

Comment: ¿De donde sacas los datos? no se ve que estes cargando ninguna lista de Categoria? ¿tienes mas código referente a esto?

Comment: Agregaste en la parte de tu `layout` esto `android:numColumns="2"` ?

Comment: Si, esa propiedad la tengo como **auto_fit**

Comment: Entonces ahí puede ocurrir un problema si no le asignas una número definido va a tomar al que llegué a alcanzar con la diferencia entre cada row, entre el tamaño de cada row. Lo mejor sería que le asignes un número, y en el tamaño de tu row le agregues `match_parent` claro en `layout_width`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Qué te muestra hasta el momento?
¿Te marca algún error? Publícalo.

Comment: ya le puse un numero a [numColums] y le cambie el [layout_width] pero sigue igual...No me da ningun error, lo unico es que me da un error en tiempo de ejecucion pero no creo que eso sea un problema, de todos modos os pongo el error.        W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb43a0f4a00, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: deberia mostrar una imagen y un texto en cada _celda_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo esta correcto, el problema es que el `ArrayList` que envías para agregar los elementos a `AdapterCategory` es vació, no va a agregar ningún elemento si este `ArrayList` no contiene datos.

Si revisas, estas declarando un `ArrayList` el cual esta vació, instancias el `Adapter` con estos datos y posteriormente lo asignas al `GridView`.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<Categoriaç> Categoria = new ArrayList<Categoriaç>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        AdapterCategory adapter = new AdapterCategory(this, Categoria);

        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Como prueba crea un `ArrayList` de objetos conteniendo texto (obviamente faltaría agregar las imagenes), ejemplo:

```
...
...
...
    ArrayList<Categoriaç> categoria = new ArrayList<Categoriaç>();
    Categoriaç cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("Java");
    categoria.add(cat);
    cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("C++");
    categoria.add(cat);
    cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("Python");
    categoria.add(cat);
    cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("C#");
    categoria.add(cat);
    cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("Swift");
    categoria.add(cat);
    cat = new Categoriaç();
    cat.setTexto("C");
    categoria.add(cat);

   AdapterCategory adapter = new AdapterCategory(this, categoria);

   gv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Con esto se visualizará tu GridView con datos.

---

No te aconsejo agregar el carácter `ç` en el nombre de la clase Objeto:

```
Categoriaç
```

> [**Regla de nomenclatura de clases**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): Los nombres de la clase, debe ser
>   sustantivos, en mayúsculas y minúsculas con la primera letra de cada
>   palabra en mayúsculas. Trata de mantener sus nombres de clases simples
>   y descriptivos. Use palabras completas, evita usar acrónimos y
>   abreviaturas (a menos que la abreviatura utilizada sea mucho más
>   amplia que la forma larga, ejemplos tales como la dirección URL o
>   HTML).

Comment: tampoco es bueno tener variables con el la primera letra en mayúsculas, sólo las clases comienzan con una mayúscula.

Comment: Te refieres a : Categoria = new ArrayList<Categoriaç>() ?

Comment: Claro no debería tener variables que comiencen con mayúsculas.

Comment: Gracias ese era el problema... y perdon por la nomenclatura, al ser un programa de prueba deje eso de lado, y lo del caracter 'ç' fue que le di a la tecla sin querer al presionar 'enter'.